# Why does regex not work for searching json?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of different documents in which I want to find certain JSON, here is an [example (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/o0j2Sk/1/).

regex: `{\"columns.*]}`
I expect to get json like this:

```
{"columns":["1",{"title":"Bad Boys For Life","value":"Bad Boys For Life"},"2","686.5","764.5","874","877","897","937",{"value":"686.5","isMeta":true},{"isMeta":true,"value":"764.5"},{"isMeta":true,"value":"874"},{"isMeta":true,"value":"877"},{"value":"897","isMeta":true},{"isMeta":true,"value":"937"},"850398",{"value":"937","isMeta":true}]}
```

But that doesn't work, why?

Comment: Why are you using a regex to search JSON? use a JSON parser. #rightToolForTheRightJob

Comment: @alfasin maybe because my document is not a JSON? I want to find JSON objects with regex, and then parse them.

Comment: Good reason :) that said, parsing it with regex is brittle, definitely not a solution for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex misses a `global` flag so it only produces one match. 
Here's the fixed version: https://regex101.com/r/o0j2Sk/2/

The reason you're getting downvoted though is that you **should not use regex to parse JSON**. It is extremely easy to parse JSON properly with any language, so that's strongly recommended to everybody.

Comment: But this still does not work. Now I get the whole JSON block in its entirety, but I only need the parts, as I indicated in the example.

Comment: ah I think I got what you mean. Try this one then: https://regex101.com/r/o0j2Sk/3/

Comment: very grateful to you, thank you